# Should I throw new error or return from if statement?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I am looping through array of coins and running a setTimeout based on when a coin bid ends and running a function called automaticBid();

```
    setTimeout(async () => {
  // placeBid(coin, username, password)
  await placeAutomaticBid(coin.username, coin.password, coin.itemId, coin.bidAmount).catch(error => console.error(error));
  // placeTest()
}, calcTime * 1000);
```

in the automaticBid()

I have this logic:

```
    if (parseInt(minBid) - 1 > bidAmount) {
    throw new Error('Bid is less than Min bid')
  }
```

It throws error but breaks the whole loop.
DO i need to catch the automaticBId()? or should I wrap all the logic in trycatch? How do I keep the loop running without breaking it by throwing this error? and continue on to the next coin?

Comment: Just `console.log` it instead of throwing an error?

Comment: Why do you want to throw an error in the first place? Throwing is a design to terminate the function immediately due to error causing the function impossible to continue. If you don't want to do so, just don't do it. You don't need it.

Comment: i want the user to somehow know that their bidamount is insufficient enough to place a bid

Comment: "*breaks the whole loop*" - what loop?

Comment: "*should I wrap all the logic in trycatch?*" - yes, you shouldn't pass a function without error handling to `setTimeout` (or for any other asynchronous callback) if you don't want it to crash your application.